# A regex to match strings with alphanumeric, spaces and punctuation

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match strings that have letters, numbers, spaces and some simple punctuation (`.,!"'/$`).  I have `^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$` and it works well for alphanumeric and spaces but not punctuation.  Help is much appreciated.

Comment: In which parts do you want to match punctuation? What have you tried? Also, do you have any sample inputs?

Comment: Why don't you just add the (escaped) punctuation characters inside of the brackets?

Comment: Well, the expression has no punctuation characters... of course it cannot work. Great source for learning regular expressions:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just add punctuation and other characters inside classes (inside the square brackets):

```
[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"'/$]*
```

This matches every string containing spaces, _, alphanumerics, commas, !, ", $, ...
Pay attention while adding some special characters, maybe you need to escape them: [more info here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: How do you fit this into a .test()?

Comment: You mean like this (Javascript ahead)? var rgx = /[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"'/$]*/; rgx.test("testme");
Or like this: /[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"'/$]*/.test("testme")

Comment: I just tried this
var r =  /[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!"'/$]*/
r.test('¬¬'); 
returns true? Am I missing something

Comment: It returns true because it matches an empty string. While the regex ends with a * (which means "match 0 or many") it evaluates to true because it doesn't find any of the given characters. Test function will evaluate to false only if you change that "*" with a "+" (which means 1..many) like this: /[A-Za-z0-9 _.,!\"\'\/$]+/ (just try exec method instead of test and see what it matches)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming from your regex that at least one alphanumeric character must be present in the string, then I'd suggest the following:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z0-9])[\w.,!"'\/$ ]+$/i
```

The `(?=.*[A-Z0-9])` lookahead checks for the presence of one ASCII letter or digit; the nest character class contains all ASCII alphanumerics including underscore (`\w`) and the rest of the punctuation characters you mentioned. The slash needs to be escaped because it's also used as a regex delimiter. The `/i` modifier makes the regex case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
check("hello dfdf asdjfnbusaobfdoad fsdihfishadio fhsdhf iohdhf");
function check(data){
var patren=/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$/;
    if(!(patren.test(data))) {
       alert('Input is not alphanumeric');       
       return false;
    }
    alert(data + " is good");
}
</script>
```